# Vuejs adding conditional style fails

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I wuld like to add the following style iwhich workss in html

```
<div style="text-decoration: line-through">
```

Now am trying this in vuejs2

```
<div :style="{'text-decoration: line-through':true}">
```

But the above doesnt work

Where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Binding an object to the `style` attribute is done by providing key / value pairs.

I suspect what you want is

```
<div :style="{'text-decoration': condition ? 'line-through' : 'initial'}">
```